Mongoose model not enforcing unique in two places
I'm working on a personal project and I'm working on user signup, one of the major things is having users with unique usernames and unique emails.  So far I have it enforcing it on email, but for some reason it just will not do it for usernames either.  It seems that when I put it in both areas it just overrides each other and allows for duplicates.  Here is my model code:
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const validator = require('validator');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        lowercase: true // Ensure lowercase for consistency
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true,
        trim: true, 
        lowercase: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 7,
        validate(value) {
            if (value.toLowerCase().includes('password')) {
                throw new Error('Password cannot contain "password"');
            }
        }
    },
    characters: [{
        character: {
            type: String
        }
    }],
    tokens: [{
        token: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    }],
    groups: [{
        group: {
            type: String
        }
    }]
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

userSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = async function () {
    const user = this;
    const token = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id.toString() }, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

    user.tokens = user.tokens.concat({ token });
    await user.save();

    return token;
}

userSchema.methods.toJSON = function () {
    const user = this;
    const userObject = user.toObject();

    delete userObject.password;
    delete userObject.tokens;

    return userObject;
}

userSchema.statics.findByCredentials = async (email, password) => {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email });

    if (!user) {
        throw new Error('Unable to login...');
    }

    const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

    if (!isMatch) {
        throw new Error('Unable to login...');
    }
    return user;
}

// Hash the plain text password before saving
userSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
    const user = this;

    if (user.isModified('password')) {
        user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 8);
    }

    next();
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = User;

Any help would be appreciated!

Did you do init(), or ensureIndex() to make the DB aware of the unique index you have in your models?

@AlexBlex I'm not super familiar with the structures yet, I'm not suer how to do something like this?

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#Model.init()
